# Getting a copy instead of a reference from std::tuple

Tags: c++11, tuples

I am storing a collection of `std::vector`s in a `std::tuple`. However, when I get an element from the tuple and modify it, I am only modifying a copy of the element returned.

```
template<typename... Ts>
class ComponentStore
{
public:
    ComponentStore()
    {

    }
    ~ComponentStore()
    {

    }

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T>& Get()
    {
        return std::get<std::vector<T>>(m_components);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> m_components;
};
```

This is how I plan to use the `ComponentStore` class:

```
ecs::component::ComponentStore<ecs::component::Position, ecs::component::Velocity> comstore;

//Get the position vector
auto positionvec = comstore.Get<ecs::component::Position>();
//Add a new position
positionvec.emplace_back(ecs::component::Position{});


//Later on, get the position vector again
auto positionvec2 = comstore.Get<ecs::component::Position>();

//But it's empty??? this is wrong. It should have 1 element.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using auto by itself, you create a variable of the deduced non-reference type, so

```
auto positionvec = comstore.Get<ecs::component::Position>();
```

creates a new vector;

you can fix this by using auto&:

```
auto& positionvec = comstore.Get<ecs::component::Position>();
```